# How to plot various multiple variables (in the same column) over a long time series?

Tags: r, plot

I am attempting to plot the following:

I have two columns. One of which is the type of disaster and the other is the year in which it occurred. I would like to do a stacked bar plot or a plot that shows the number of each event by year. For example a graph that would show the number of tornado events, hurricanes, and fires that occurred yearly over 40 years all in the same graph. Do I need to split them into various columns or is there a way to do this as is without manipulating the data. I am also curious if there is a way to count the values by year as that would facilitate this process.

Thanks in advance! Data below...

```
             inctype decdate
1            Tornado    1953
2            Tornado    1953
3              Flood    1953
4            Tornado    1953
5              Flood    1953
6            Tornado    1953
7            Tornado    1953
8              Flood    1953
9              Flood    1953
10              Fire    1953
11             Flood    1953
12             Other    1953
13           Tornado    1953
14             Flood    1954
15           Tornado    1954
16             Flood    1954
17             Flood    1954
18        Earthquake    1954
19             Flood    1954
20             Flood    1954
21         Hurricane    1954
22         Hurricane    1954
23         Hurricane    1954
24         Hurricane    1954
25         Hurricane    1954
26             Flood    1954
27         Hurricane    1954
28         Hurricane    1954
29             Flood    1954
30             Other    1954
31           Volcano    1955
32             Flood    1955
33           Tornado    1955
```

Comment: please share an example of you data using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

Getting the counts is very straightforward, so let's start with that. The easiest way is probably just the built in function `table`:

```r
 table(df$inctype, df$decdate)
            
#>             1953 1954 1955
#>  Earthquake    0    1    0
#>  Fire          1    0    0
#>  Flood         5    7    1
#>  Hurricane     0    7    0
#>  Other         1    1    0
#>  Tornado       6    1    1
#>  Volcano       0    0    1
```

To make a stacked bar plot, you have several options. If for some reason you want to use only base R functions, you can do something like:

```r
colours <- c("#440154FF", "#443A83FF", "#31688EFF", "#21908CFF",
             "#35B779FF", "#8FD744FF", "#FDE725FF")

barplot(table(df$inctype, df$decdate), 
        col = colours, 
        border = "gray20", 
        font.axis = 2,
        xlab = "year", 
        font.lab = 2)

legend(list(x = 2.6, y = 16), 
       legend = levels(as.factor(df$inctype)),
       fill = colours)
```

[image]

Though perhaps the simplest and most popular way to get a stacked bar plot without manipulating your data is to use the `ggplot2` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(decdate, fill = inctype)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

This has the benefit of having a huge number of options to get something a bit more aesthetically pleasing:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(decdate, fill = inctype)) + 
  geom_bar(color = "black", size = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "Year", fill = "Event type") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]